# Not able to retrieve or create database objects inside django view function inside aws amazon linux v2

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-3.6, amazon-rds

I am using amazon linux v2 with python 3.6 and django 2.2.0:
I have set up database using RDS MYSQL DB instance. I am able to retrieve and/or create objects in python shell but not able to retrieve and/or create when using inside view function.

```
pqs=ExpertQa.objects.filter(category="public")
return render(request,'ebdjango/expert-qa.html',{'pqs':pqs})
```

the above code isn't fetching objects.
I have tried passing list, string everything works fine.Just not able to get database objects.

Please can anyone provide the solution? Is there any other syntax for linux?

Comment: Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation(spaces) matters:

```
pqs = ExpertQa.objects.filter(category="public")
return render(request,'ebdjango/expert-qa.html',{'pqs':pqs})
```

Comment: Sorry, It was typing mistake in the  question but indentation is proper in code.

Comment: so ExpertQa.objects.filter(category="public") gives results in python shell right?

Comment: yes totally```>>> from ebdjango.models import ExpertQa
>>> ExpertQa.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (1)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (2)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (3)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (4)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (5)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (6)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (7)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (8)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (9)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (10)>, <ExpertQa: ExpertQa object (11)>, ...```

Comment: Can you please suggest or guide me further?

Comment: print those values and check the logs, to see if there is a connection issue

Comment: I am able to edit,print values from objects, can you tell me where to check for logs?